# Struts i18n showing unicode instead of special char

Tags: jsp, struts2, internationalization

I'm currently working on a struts migration. I upgraded from struts 2.2.3.1 to 2.5.10.1, and tiles from 2.2.2 to 3.0.8

For forms labels translation I use some properties files which are ISO-8859-1 encoded. This used to work, euro symbols which is in the file like " \u20AC " used to show properly on navigators.

But after librairies upgrades, the code \u20AC is shown directly on navigator, instead of €.

To display i18n labels in JSP I use following code :

```
<s:text name="%{getText('lbl.to.pay', null, price)}"/>
```

In message_en.properties I got :

```
lbl.to.pay=Your fees are {0}\u20AC
```

Which is supposed to display :

> "Your fees are 100€"

But instead I have :

> "Your fees are 100\u20AC"

In every jsp I have :

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/javascript; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
...
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

In web.xml I got :

```
<jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>


...
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

And in struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
```

This config used to work with old libraries, and I didn't change anything about that after libraries upgrading.

If I add an € directly in jsp, it's shown properly.

Any idea about what to do?

**Edit** :

This is working perfectly when I use :

```
<s:text name="lbl.ccip.checkout.to.pay" />
```

But still have same problem with :

```
<s:text name="%{getText('lbl.ccip.checkout.to.pay')}" />
```

So, the problem seems to be with the getText() method, which I have to use in the example above cause I use a placeholder {0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if I use  instead of calling getText() this is working perfectly :

```
<s:text name="lbl.to.pay" >
    <s:param value="%{price}"/>
</s:text>
```